# Decompressing a gz file larger than available memory

Tags: c, compression, gzip

I am on a device with 1 GB of memory and 16 GB of SSD disk space, but I want to use a 15 GB compressed PCAP file to stream IP data over the ethernet port.

Obviously, I cannot just decompress the file as I haven't enough disk space for that, and even if I did, the decompression would take too long. Does the gz file format support some form of streaming decompression so that I can stream the file without running out of disk space?

Comment: I've used `gzopen` and `gzread` to do something similar in the past. Open the file, read however much you want, do whatever you want with the data then repeat the read loop until you run out of file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does the gz file format support some form of streaming decompression so that I can stream the file without running out of disk space?

Yes, it is possible to decompress gzip format incrementally.  This is in fact [Zlib](https://zlib.net/)'s normal mode of operation when decompressing gzip.

Or for a higher-level approach, [the `zcat` or`gunzip -c` or `gzip -dc` command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zcat) decompresses a gzipped file to its standard output.

Comment: Ah, it's as straightforward as that! I couldn't find a good answer by searching, but I didn't actually try anything myself.